# How to sum and average two column values and display the result in another column

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, vba

I need to merge 4 files together in Excel VBA. I managed to do it so far as shown below (more data in actual sheet):

```
 F          P           L           V              W
80          50       Completed   Incomplete   
80          70       Completed   Incomplete   
80          70       Completed   Completed   
80          70       Completed   Completed   
30          20       Completed   Completed
80          50       Completed   Incomplete   
80          70       Completed   Incomplete   
80          70       Completed   Completed   
80          70       Completed   Completed   
30          20       Completed   Completed
```

In order to get the value "Completed" in column `W` I need to fulfill the following criteria:

- Columns `L` and `V` must be "Completed"
- Average marks of `F + P` must be greater than or equal to 70%

Otherwise, column `W` will be "Incomplete."

Here is the code that I have written, which does not calculate the average marks of columns `F` and `P`:

```
Sub OverallStatus()

Dim x As Long

For x = 1 To 65536
    If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$L$" & x), "Completed") And InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$V$" & x), "Completed") > 0 Then
        Sheet1.Range("$W$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$W$" & x) & "Completed"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The result that I get by using the above code is not accurate, because it is not checking the second criteria (the average marks of `F` and `P`):

```
     F          P           L           V              W
    80          50       Completed   Incomplete   
    80          70       Completed   Incomplete   
    80          70       Completed   Completed      Completed
    80          70       Completed   Completed      Completed 
    30          20       Completed   Completed      Completed
    80          50       Completed   Incomplete   
    80          70       Completed   Incomplete   
    80          70       Completed   Completed      Completed 
    80          70       Completed   Completed      Completed
    30          20       Completed   Completed      Completed
```

How can I sum up the average of columns `F` and `P` and use the result to display the correct text in column `W`?

Comment: Well, seems like your code completely ignores the average marks F and P. Why don't you try to put another `If` statement and test the average there? vba is not my forte, but that seems like a logical thing to do for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this code (thanks to @SiddharthRout for `lastrow` code):

```
Sub OverallStatus()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With sheet1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
             lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                         After:=.Range("A1"), _
                         Lookat:=xlPart, _
                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastrow = 1
        End If
        For x = 1 To lastrow
            If .Range("L" & x) = "Completed" And .Range("V" & x) = "Completed" _
                And .Range("F" & x) + .Range("P" & x) > 140 Then
                .Range("W" & x) = "Completed"
            Else
                .Range("W" & x) = "Incomplete"
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

At first I found last non empty row `lastrow` instead looping until 65536. Then I've added `And .Range("F" & x) + .Range("P" & x) > 140 Then` wich means that average `(Fx+Px)/2 > 70` or equals `(Fx+Px)>140`

If your data stored with percent format, you should change `140` to `1.4`

Comment: Thank you so much, it's helping me a lottttt. Sorry, May i ask one more question. Let say column "L", and column "V" is empty and its suppose to display "Incomplete" as well. Should i display            If .Range("L" & x) = """","Completed" And .Range("V" & x) = """", "Completed" _

Comment: No, you shoudn't. My code fills `.Range("W" & x)` with "completed" only in case when `Lx` and `Vx` are completed and average of F and P >70. In all other cases (include when L or V is empty) it fills `.Range("W" & x)` with "incomplete"

Comment: My code stop running when column "L" and column "V" is empty. Then the next line come with content again. Due to this "lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row". Can i change to selected whole column all the way?

Comment: I keep using the wrong methods. I learnt something new. Finally work perfectly. Thank you so muchhhhhhhh.>.<

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time job then an Excel formula would be far more appropriate.

Paste the Excel formula below in cell W2.

```
=IF(AND(L2="Completed",V2="Completed",AVERAGE(F2,P2)>70),"Completed","Incomplete")
```

Then copy the cell into other cells as needed.